# Count rows with certain condition and still show all rows

Tags: mysql, count

My table looks like this:

```
col1      col2
Denmark   Yes
Denmark   No
Denmark   Yes
Brazil    Yes
Brazil    No
Brazil    No
```

I want to count the distinct countries and tally the number of `Yes` in a separate column. For example:

```
col3      col4
Denmark   2
Brazil    1
```

What is the best way to count all the `'Yes'` and show all the distinct countries from `col1`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1 As Col3, SUM(CASE WHEN col2 = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As col4
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col1
```